# Dell Laptop battery drains after shutting down

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron

My dell laptop battery drains after shutting down.Only after removing the battery and placing it again after shutdown stops battery drain.Its getting heated up after shutting down?Why it is not shutting down . I've windows os running in my laptop

Comment: Does it shut down completely, with power lights off?

Comment: Update BIOS and the Power Driver. Restart and test shutdown.

Comment: Try to [Turn Off Fast Startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html). Try also to [Disable Hibernation](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-enable-disable-hibernate-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @gronostaj Yes it shut downs completely.